# How set css variable on `::before` or `::after` through JS

Tags: javascript, css

Sound simple enough.

I Just want to set some `--progress` variable on DOM element and read it through some attribute on that `element:before`.

Setting CSS-variable on the element is just `element.style.setProperty('--progress',value)`. But it turns out that the value is not inherited to pseudo-element. even if declared with :

```css
@property --progress{
  syntax: '<number>';
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 0;
}
```

so how can I do that without declare `CSS class` for each percent like :

```css
element.p-1:before{
 --progress:1%;
}

element.p-2:before{
 --progress:2%;
}

....
```

Comment: *it turns out that the value is not inherited to pseudo-element* --> they are inherited. The issue must somewhere else

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333 I am setting CSS variable on pseudo element without any problem

Comment: rigth , I do a test with diffrent variable and it work, now I wonder what happen.  I think maybe just from ":root" they not inherit.